# ActiveStorage S3 WORM (write once, read many) support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I'm developing a Rails application in AWS that requires a strong WORM (write once, read many) guarantee. Currently, we're using S3. Ideally, I would like this to be at the level of the storage service (S3, Azure Blob, etc), but would settle for protections at the ActiveStorage level.

I am aware of S3 Object Lock. But based on my understanding and testing, Object Lock doesn't prevent you from creating a new version of the same file, and ActiveStorage will simply read the newest version. So Object Lock protects the old version of the file, but the application only sees the latest version.

We would like to stay inside the AWS ecosystem. But with no other apparent solution apparent, we're leaning towards using immutable blobs (Azure) or bucket locks (Google Cloud Storage).

Thanks in advance for any advice on the matter!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use normal IAM permissions?  I have a `s3readonly` role that I use for this exact thing.  Your application would have one area that writes files.  This section of code would use a profile that has permission to write but everything else would use the read only role.

Comment: @stdunbar different IAM permissions doesn't solve the issue.  For ActiveStorage to be able to write to the bucket the first time, it must have IAM policy that allows for writing.  One minute later, ActiveStorage will still be using that same IAM policy.  So there is nothing to prevent ActiveStorage from overwriting said file.

Comment: So the issue is that active storage doesn't support multiple roles, not that AWS can't support your use case in general.  It sounds like if you're stuck with that limitation then other vendors may be a better solution.

Comment: "not that AWS can't support your use case in general"  @stdunbar it's a combination of limitations in ActiveRecord AND limitations in AWS.  If I were in Azure, immutable blobs would do the trick.